# Ion-item problems

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an ion-item that contains a dp-datepicker, the problem is that the ion-item does not let me show the calendar when I select it, that is, it hides it inside the ion-item. Any ideas?

Code:

```html
<ion-item lines="none">
  <dp-date-picker class="dp-material ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched"></dp-date-picker>
</ion-item>
```

style:

```css
ion-item {
  border: 2px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

imagen:
[image]

What I want is to show the calendar outside the ion-item. Thank you!

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime/ you can use built in date picker instead of other outside module

Comment: Yes, I use it and it works perfectly, but I don't like the layout of ion-datetime, I want the calendar to come out and not the native ionic date picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use better a mat-datepicker within a mat-form-field:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Custom calendar header</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker [calendarHeaderComponent]="exampleHeader"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

see also [here](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples)